# Spring Boot project keeps complaining about java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException even though I have added the dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, jaxb, java-17

Upgrading Spring Boot from 2.1.9 JDK 8 to 2.7.16 JDK 17
I am aware that JAXB needs to be included as a dependency and I have added the following lines to build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.4'
implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '4.0.3'
```

But the compile fails because gradle is excluding the jars in the compileJava task

```
Excluding [javax.activation:javax.activation-api, com.zaxxer:HikariCP-java7, ognl:ognl, org.javassist:javassist, com.mchange:c3p0, org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec, javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api]
```

Here is my entire build.gradle file. I am unable to figure out why the JAXB error is being thrown even though the dependency has been included. Can someone spot what I am doing wrong?

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.16'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.refirx.application'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
    extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    annotationProcessor 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.3.7.Final'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-quartz', version: '2.4.5'
    implementation group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: '2.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.14.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.11.2'
    implementation 'com.graphhopper.external:jackson-datatype-jts:0.10-2.5-1'
    implementation 'org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:1.18.2'
    implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.15.3')
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-aws-messaging', version: '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.875'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rekognition:1.11.303'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-sqs', version: '1.11.1000'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.9'
    implementation group: 'org.redisson', name: 'redisson-spring-data-20', version: '3.8.0'
    //implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-cloudwatch2', version: '1.7.1'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:5.6.1.Final'
    implementation group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-admin', version: '8.1.0'
    implementation group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '5.7.1'
    implementation group: 'org.sejda.imageio', name: 'webp-imageio', version: '0.1.6'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.activation', name: 'javax.activation', version: '1.2.0'
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.4'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '4.0.3'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

    implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.30.7'
    implementation group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-drive', version: 'v3-rev188-1.25.0'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.11.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-joda', version: '2.11.2'
    implementation group: 'eu.bitwalker', name: 'UserAgentUtils', version: '1.21'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    implementation group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.6'
    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.10.5'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-redis', version: '2.1.8.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version: '2.9.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.17'
    implementation group: 'net.minidev', name: 'json-smart', version: '2.3'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.plugin', name: 'spring-plugin-core', version: '1.2.0.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.1'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-freemarker', version: '2.5.6'
    implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time-hibernate', version: '1.4'
    implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-blob', version: '12.7.0'
    implementation group: 'org.imgscalr', name: 'imgscalr-lib', version: '4.2'
    implementation group: 'com.twelvemonkeys.imageio', name: 'imageio-jpeg', version: '3.6.1'
    implementation group: 'com.twelvemonkeys.imageio', name: 'imageio-core', version: '3.6.1'
    implementation group: 'com.twelvemonkeys.imageio', name: 'imageio-bmp', version: '3.6.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-imaging', version: '1.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-core:2.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:2.1.0'
    implementation group: 'com.drewnoakes', name: 'metadata-extractor', version: '2.18.0'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.3.8'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:razorpay-java:1.3.9'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
}
```

I have researched and added the fix that everyone is suggesting about including JAXB in the dependencies but it is not resolving the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, at least for me, I needed to add these 4 dependencies/jars to my project

```
 1. javax.activation-1.2.0.jar
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/javax.activation
implementation group: 'com.sun.activation', name: 'javax.activation', version: '1.2.0'

 2. jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api
implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'

 3. jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core
implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '2.3.0'

 4. jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl
implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.0'
```

Don't forget to pull your dependencies with Gradle once you add these dependencies.

Also if you are using JDK11 or higher you need to have at least all of your Hibernate version at least 5.4 or higher.

Comment: I tried, but it still doesn't help. Looking at the gradle in debug mode, it looks like the exception is being thrown by Hibernate annotation processor -   annotationProcessor('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.3.7.Final') in the build.gradle. I wonder if the gradle dependencies are picked up before the annotation processing stage? I have resolved the issue  by replacing the gradle entry as follows: annotationProcessor('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'). This seems to resolve the issue, but I don't know why.

Comment: I updated my answer regarding your hibernate issue with JDK version.